# Does it necessary to enable the "keepalive" in the JTDS for the performance increase?

Tags: java, database, performance, jtds

How much will performance increase when enabled the config of "keepalive" in JTDS? I reviewed the [jtds document](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html) today and found one interesting config "sockekeepalive" never noticed before. And did u test the performance effect in your local? Since the default value of is "false", I guess there maybe some overhead for using "keepalive" in real production env.

Thanks in adv!

Vance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be astonished if it made the slightest difference. The Javadoc is out of sync with itself but all it appears to do is call Socket.setKeepalive(), which has nothing to do with performance (unlike HTTP keep-alive).

Comment: Not quite sure your answer but seems I need to research for the "socket.setKeepalive" related articles.

Comment: @Vance what exactly makes you 'unsure' about 'astonished if it made the slightest difference'?

Comment: So does this "socket.setKeepAlive" will help JTDS "reuse" connection from app to database?

Comment: @Vance TCP keep-alive is a mechanism to (a) detect connections that have been dropped, after two hours, and (b) allow idle connections to persist for longer than two hours. Saving a connect() every two hours isn't going to speed up your application. There are reasons to use TCP keep-alive: that isn't one of them.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! It really can't gain any performance from that config. :-)